# Playing sound and video out of a streaming .asf file in iOS application

Tags: ios, ios7, ffmpeg, asf

I need to read audio and video out of a .asf file that is streamed to my iOS7 application. 
I've compiled ffmpeg but I'm notre really sure this is the way to go. If this is the good tool, I do not know where to go from here.
Any pointer ?

Comment: More information is needed. Is your application using the FFmpeg libraries or the `ffmpeg` cli tool? What do you mean by "streamed"?

Comment: My appel reads a .asf stream trop which I need to display the vidéo and the sound. As iOS does not support .asf streaming I found ffmpeg and wondered if this could be used from within the app (nous cli then) for this purpose.